# SQL Server View responds differently based on search value given in where condition

Tags: sql-server

I have a view with 10 columns and it has a column `CustomerType` of datatype `int` and the distinct values for this column are 2 and 10. When I search with value as 2, it gives me a result with 15000 records in 6 seconds. However the problem is when I search with value as 10, it takes 1 minute and 43 seconds to fetch 3500 records. What should be the reason and how to resolve it?

PS: there are no other joins apart from view_Name and where has only one condition as

```
Select Name, Code 
From CustomersView 
Where CustomerType = 10
```

Comment: It isn't possible to answer a question like this without understanding more about your environment.  in the short term, I highly recommend running both queries from Management Studio and reviewing their query plans.  Otherwise, please share the structure of the view.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an index on the column that returns the fast result .. may be CustomerType.

Please do post the code of the view and the query that you are trying to write against the view. With the time it took to return the result.

Posting the query plan will be helpful too